# Tiny bootstrap NavBar on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So the site I am working on will be a mobile only version of a main site. So I naturally decided to go with bootstrap. We forced the navbar to always be collapsed with some css, and when viewed from within a desktop browser and shrunk the window size, the navbar looks fine. Nice size compared to the body text. However, when we uploaded it to the server to test on actual mobile devices, the body text is a good readable size, but the navbar font and icons are tiny and are definitely not suitable for mobile users. I'm not to sure about what code to show, so I'll include the custom css file that deals with navbar colour change and the always collapsed look.

```
.navbar-custom {
background-color:#6BC1C2;
color:#ffffff;
border-radius:0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color:#fff;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
  color: #378182;
  background-color: #76CBCC;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
   color: #378182;
   background-color:#84E3E4;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    color:#eeeeee;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #1FACAD;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #888;
}

.nav-icons{
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.btn-Link{
   color: white;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}


.navbar-header {
    float: none;
 }
 .navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
 }
 .navbar-collapse {
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
}
.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none!important;
}
.navbar-nav {
    float: none!important;
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
}
.navbar-nav>li {
    float: none;
}
.navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {display: block !important; }
```

HTML for Navbar

```
<body>
    <!--Navigation Bar starts here!-->
    <nav class="nav navbar-custom">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigationBar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Website</a>

                <div class="navbar-left nav-icons">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav" style="list-style-type: none;">
                        <li> <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <a href="tel: 1-705-503-3455" class="btn-Link">
                                        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
 <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                    <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=80 Bradford Street Barrie Ontario" class="btn-Link">
                                        <i class="fa fa-square-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                    </a>
                                </span>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navigationBar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span> <i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About Us <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="services.html">Services <i class="fa fa-wrench fa-lg"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="addiction_and_trauma.html">Addiction &amp; Trauma Center <i class="fa fa-commenting fa-lg"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="resources.html">Resources <i class="fa fa-archive fa-lg"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Navigation Bar Ends here!-->
</body>
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cv18nsyy/)

Image of the navbar on Mobile, ignore the Icons. They were fine until we started playing around with it.

[image]

Comment: add your html code to your question too. Create either a jsfiddle or a bootply, that will help us help you!

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast THere we go. Updated the post. Hope it helps

Comment: Based on the code you provided it doesn't seem like that's where the problem is. The easiest thing to do (if you're still having problems) would be to provide a URL to a test environment that is showing the problem.